# suppose ${a_n} \to a$ and ${b_n} \to b$, prove ${a_n}^{b_n} \to a^b$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

suppose ${a_n} \to a$ and ${b_n} \to b$, prove ${a_n}^{b_n} \to a^b$

edit: this question came prior to continouity and functions, so I guess i should be using arithmethics of limits and this kind of knowledge..

I figured so far, using limit arithmetics ,that

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{{a_n}}{a} = a/a = 1$$

raising all to the power of b, gives us

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{a_n}{a}\right)^b = 1^b=1 $$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{a_n}{a}\right)^b = \frac{a_n^b}{a^b} =1 \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n^b=a^b $$

I couldn't get any further, saying something about ${b_n}$..

Some help would be super helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: You are clearly using the continuity of the function $x\mapsto x^b$ in the step $$(a_n/a)^b\to1^b=1$$ so why not just use the same property (continuity of the exponential and natural logarithm) to prove the general case?

Comment: Can you use continuity of exponential function?

Comment: The map $\Bbb R_{>0}\times \Bbb R_{\ge0}\to \Bbb R_{>0}$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto x^y$ is continuous in both $x$ and $y$. The result follows immediately.

Comment: As noted, you need to give us your definition of $x^y$ where $y$ is irrational.  Otherwise we will use our definition (as an answer did), which may involve the disallowed "continuity and functions" like continuity of $\log$.

Answer (score 2):

By continuity of the exponential function, natural logarithm and multiplication, which is these three things:

- $\lim_n a_n = a \implies \lim_n e^{a_n} = e^a$,
- $\lim_n a_n = a \implies \lim_n \ln a_n = \ln a$ (which follows from the above by the general result which says that the inverse of a continuous real function of a real variable is continuous),
- $\lim_n a_n = a,\, \lim_n b_n = b \implies \lim_n (a_n b_n) = ab$,

we have:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{b_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}e^{b_n\ln a_n} =e^{\lim_{n}(b_n\ln a_n)} = e^{\lim_{n}b_n\cdot \lim_{n}(\ln a_n)} = e^{b\ln(\lim_{n}a_n)} = e^{b\ln a} = a^b.$$

*Remark.* All of the bullets are standard results. In particular, the first bullet amounts to most of the work. Couple of lemmas are needed, in short you want $\lim_n x_n= 0 \implies \lim_n e^{x_n} = 1$ and the usual $e^{x+y} = e^x e^y$.

Comment: this question came prior to continouity and functions, so I guess i should be using arithmethics of limits and this kind of knowledge..

Comment: @Gal Yossipov, the question is basically about continuity of exponential function, so there is no arithmetic that will allow you to circumvent it. You need to start from a definition of exponential function if that's the case.

Comment: @Gal Yossipov, I've edited my answer with a bit more details. When I say "standard", I mean "can be found in any analysis textbook". Before I'm willing to write any more details, I would like some feedback on what have you actually proved in your course so far, because this answer will otherwise turn into a textbook chapter.